# What is なでしこ in なでしこJAPAN

Tags: translation

I think this what the women's soccer team is called, but I'm not clear on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is short for `大和撫子` (yamatonadeshiko), which refers to the stereotypical attributes (particular kind of beauty and purity, etc.) that are traditionally considered to be observed among ideal Japanese women. It also refers to Japanese women with such attributes. The male counterpart is `日本男児` (nippondanji). This meaning was derived from the plant name ナデシコ as Dave points out. The `ヤマト` (yamato) [old name of Japan] part was added in order to distinguish it from `カラナデシコ`.

Comment: ナデシコ is also a flower: [(fringed) pink (Dianthus)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dianthus)

Comment: @Dave That's right.

Comment: I would like to see some examples of 大和撫子 and 日本男児. Can you refer me to some anime or movies?

Comment: Dave's comment should probably be merged into the answer, since the flower is featured (albeit abstractly) on the uniform: the "collar rectangle" on the men's uniform is red, but on the women's it's pink to match the color of the dianthus.

Comment: It would probably be worth pointing out that 大和 is an old word for Japan (kinda like 'Britain' is for the United Kingdom).

Answer (score 3):

It's a nickname for the Japan women's World Cup team: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%83%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E5%A5%B3%E5%AD%90%E4%BB%A3%E8%A1%A8

Comment: Strictly speaking, “Nadeshiko Japan” refers to the national soccer team of Japan, not necessarily in the FIFA Women’s World Cup.  Naturally they also compete in the Olympic Games and other international competitions.

Comment: There's also the Nadeshiko League, which, from what I heard on the radio today, is back in action this coming Saturday (so not much rest for the newly crowned world champions).